# Why is this function not executing on page load? (How to create HTML option using JavaScript at page load)

Tags: javascript

I want to fill a dropdown list and I've written the following code:

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2">
window.onload = fillDropDown();

function fillDropDown() {

        var ddl = document.getElementById("dia");
    var theOption = new Option;
    var x;
    var i;

    for(i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
        x = i + 1;
        theOption.text = x;
        theOption.value = x;
        ddl.options[i] = theOption;
    }


}

</script>
   <body>
    <form>
           <select id=dia></select>
    </form>
   <body>
```

It isn't working, any idea why?

Comment: -1 for "isn't working" on a non-novice post. Please take the time to come up with a minimal test-case (e.g. jsfiddle) and explain what "isn't working". I know the answer: it is the same as in *a hundred other posts* that deal with callbacks "executing now". (Debugging would have reveled this.)

Comment: @pst: I'm not a javascript developer (i.e. not knowing of the existence of tools like jsfiddle). Being a long-time user doesn't make me a javascript developer, could you have suggested it instead of downvoting? What isn't working is explicit on the "function not executing on page load" title. I'll just flag your comment as unhelpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: Even without knowing about it, -1 for "isn't working". Identifying a problem is a crucial skill.

Comment: Cool, so you don't like the words, even though enough context to quickly formulate an answer was provided - Title of question: "function not executing on page load".

Comment: No, what I dislike is SO filling up with questions that are far too localized that show no effort (on the posters part) of being solved locally. For instance, was there an error message? (There is, in the console, if you looked. That would be a start.)

Comment: A neutral comment: It would be better to put as title `How to create HTML option using JavaScript at page load`. This way, it could be more handy for other Web Developers to find their solution. :)

Comment: @pst: What you call "no effort" is inexperience with a particular skill. As I said: I don't work with js, it didn't even occur to me to look into the console, I'm learning js, I've never done that before. Helpful comment: look into the browser's error console. Don't assume that inexperience equals lack of effort or curiosity and make that an excuse for your own rudeness. Don't make Stackoverflow a place where people would be afraid to ask and learn something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have some errors in your code.

**1.** The first *common* mistake is the following:

```
window.onload = fillDropDown();
```

This previous code is registering the result of the called function `fillDropDown` and then assigning its results into `window.onload`. Thus, this *will never* do something. To register an event you have to *assign a function* not the *result of a called function*. The difference is this:

```
window.onload = fillDropDown; // Without the parentheses.
```

**2.** Another mistake I found, is about the creation of the `option` element. The **better way** to create HTML element in JavaScript is using the *almost-standard* `document.createElement` function.

**3.** Also your HTML markup has an error. Your `select` is written: `<select id=dia></dia>` and it should be `<select id="dia"></select>`;

So, with all theses changes highlighted the resulting code will be like this:

```
window.onload = fillDropDown;

function fillDropDown() {

    var ddl = document.getElementById("dia");
    var theOption;
    var x;
    var i;

    for (i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
        x = i + 1;
        theOption = document.createElement('option');
        theOption.label = x;
        theOption.value = x;
        ddl.add(theOption, null);
    }


}​
```

And it works like a charm. You can see it in action in this live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dyjLS/

**Note:** I **highly recommend** to use a JavaScript library such as `jQuery` to do this, since it will deal with almost all the cross-browser inconsistencies. If you use it, your code will look like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
    var $select = $('#dia');
    for ( var i = 1 ; i < 32 ; i++) {
      var x = i + 1;
      $select.append('<option value='+ x +'>'+ x +'</option>');
    }
  });
</script>
```

¡Voilà!

Comment: @Hoque first mover advantage, or unwillingness to read a lengthy answer

Comment: But Musa's answer does not indicate that the problem of HTML tag i.e. <select id=dia></dia>

Comment: the select closed as </dia> was a typo on my part, the code from I where I copied didn't have it. Thanks for providing a full answer.

Answer (score 4):

`<script language="JavaScript1.2">` should be `<script type="text/javascript">`
Also `window.onload = fillDropDown();` should be `window.onload = fillDropDown;`

Comment: Thanks, infinitely more helpful than a rude longtime user. Proved that enough context was given to formulate an answer.

Comment: @omgzor, even if this is the right solution you will end up with another problem creating the `option` element. Please, double check my answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10406424/439427